# How to select a column element according to the size of another column elements?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame named `a`. I want to get the top most used time apps.

```
import pandas as pd 
a=pd.DataFrame({'user':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2],'app':['k','p','s','k','p','s','t'],'time':[5,10,15,10,5,3,1]})
```

`Input:`

```
      user   app   time
0        1      k     5
1        1      p    10
2        1      s    15
3        2      k    10
4        2      p     5
5        2      s     3
6        2      t     1
```

For example, I want to get the top two most used `apps` according the column `time`. I expect the output as follows.

`Expected:`

```
      user top1_app top2_app
0        1      s     p
1        2      k     p
```

As you see, `user 1` has the longest time to use the `app` called `s`, and has the second longest time to use the `app` called `p`.

Hopefully for help and thanks!

Comment: Nice and clear question, providing commands for constructing the sample DateFrame, displaying it and the requested output, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rank the time column and then reshape

```
a['time1'] = a.groupby('user').time.rank(method = 'dense', ascending = False).map({1.0 : 'top1_app', 2.0 : 'top2_app'})

a = a.dropna().pivot('user', 'time1', 'app')
a.columns.name = None
a.reset_index(inplace = True)


    user    top1_app    top2_app
0   1       s           p
1   2       k           p
```

Comment: Thanks, and I find that if the column `time` contains the same large value, using the method `first` is better than the method `dense`.